# Unexpected vertical lines when resizing a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, datagrid

I'm working with a DataGrid using the following code:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridBids" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          Background="#0d4338"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Bids}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          IsManipulationEnabled="False"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          GridLinesVisibility="None"
          Margin="0,0,0,0"
          BorderThickness="0">

    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0d4338"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#11b376"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Agent" Width="*"  Binding="{Binding Agent}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Quantity}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Buy" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Price, StringFormat='N2'}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

The DataGrid works exactly as I expected when I open it:
[image]

But when I resize the window, these unexpected white vertical lines show up constantly (though not always):
[image]

For some reason the white line only shows up between the second and third columns, and always vertically.

I don't know whether this is a WPF bug or not, but either way I'd like to fix it.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be something weird with the rendering. Since your columns are all intended to have the same background, your style could target `DataGridRow` instead of `DataGridCell` like the snippet below. Note: I am using transparent since the `DataGrid` already has the background color you want, but you could just as easily use your green color `"#0d4338"`.

```xml
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <!--Target DataGridRow instead... -->
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#11b376" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

This got rid of any weird aliasing for me that I saw when resizing the grid, but I could not reproduce exactly what you showed.